# Warning: Error in array: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' in Kmeans Clustering

Tags: r, shiny, k-means

I used this code in shiny, and there's some error with my code. I am using render UI and reactive to automatically show the display:

> Warning: Error in array: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

```
 server <- function(input, output) {


  filedata <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    # infile <- input$file1
    # if (is.null(infile)) {
    #   # User has not uploaded a file yet
    #   return(NULL)
    # }
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
             header = input$header,
             sep = input$sep,
             quote = input$quote)
  })

  selectedData <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    infile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    data <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = input$header,
                     sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote)

    filedata()[, c(input$var1, input$var2)]

  })

  clusters <- reactive({
    kmeans(selectedData(), input$clusters)

  })
```

Comment: Is the kmeans called before you upüloaded any csv? If yes that is the problem and you have to sharpern your `req` statement so that it doesn't happen

Comment: hi @BertilBaron yes i usde kmeans with csv file, when i uploaded the csv file the error mention in above.. what do you mean in sharpen your req please advise